# delete first two char from each line in text file -sed

Tags: php, bash, sed

I am using PHP file which execute sed:

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'sed -i -r \'s/.{2}//\' $text_files_path/File.txt 2>&1'");
```

This statement will delete the first 2 character from file.txt.
How to delete the first 2 char from (each line) in the file?

File.text:

```
< TTGCATGCAAAAATTT
< AAAAAAATTTTGCTGA
< AAGGTTCCCCCTTAGT
```

**Edit 1:**

```
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'sed -i -r 's/^..//' $text_files_path/File.txt 2>&1'");
```

This works but, it concatenate all lines together:
File.text after above command:

```
TTGCATGCAAAAATTTAAAAAAATTTTGCTGAAAGGTTCCCCCTTAGT
```

Comment: I dunno where you got the idea that you should call sed via bash from PHP but it's definitely **not** the right way to do this. Open the file and read the lines in PHP. If all you want to do is remove the first two characters, you don't even need to use regular expressions; a simple `$line = substr($line, 2);` would be the best option.

Comment: @Tom Fenech I am using more than 70 GB file.

Comment: Using `sed -i` doesn't do anything magic - you're still going to have to create two copies of your huge file. You should use PHP, open the input file and write the substring to another file.

Comment: @Tom Fenech I prefer using sed.

Comment: I'm guessing you're going to do this only once, if so why not directly use `sed` instead of wrapping in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't call sed via bash to do something that PHP can do natively. It's a complete anti-pattern. Worryingly, I have seen the exact same thing in another question quite recently...

I hope you've got plenty of free disk space:

```
$input_filename = "$text_files_path/File.txt";
$output_filename = 'path/to/temp/output.txt';

$input_file = fopen($input_filename, 'rb');
$output_file = fopen($output_filename, 'wb');

while (($line = fgets($input_file)) !== false) {
    fwrite($output_file, substr($line, 2));
}

fclose($input_file);
fclose($output_file);

rename($output_filename, $input_filename);
```

Open the input file for reading and the temporary output file for writing. Use binary mode in both cases to avoid issues related to different line endings on different systems.

Read each line of the input and write the substring from the second character to the temporary output.

Close both files and then overwrite the input with the temporary file.

Technically this could actually be implemented in-place but the resulting script would be much more complicated and you would run further risk of corrupting your input file if things went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use PHP, then you can `explode()` the file into individual lines and then use `substr()` to drop the first two characters before joining the lines back into a single string separated with a new line:

```
// Set the results array.
$result = array();

// Split the file into lines.
$file = $text_files_path . '/File.txt';
$lines = explode("\n", $file);

// Cut the first two characters of each line and add to the results array.
foreach($lines AS $line) {
    $result[] = substr($line, 2);
}

// Split the result back into lines.
$result = implode("\n", $result);
```

Comment: I am using 70 GB file. Is this will successfully works?

Comment: Oh dear, no :) Use bash in that case, @MarcoS appears to be on the case.

Comment: MacroS code does not works. TheProphetOfRa does but, it join all lines together.

Answer (score 0):

`s/^..//` That should give you the result you need.

`^` points to the start of the line then the `.` will match any character

Comment: This works fine. But, why it concatenate all lines together? I mean, It produces: TTGCATGCAAAAATTTAAAAAAATTTTGCTGAAAGGTTCCCCCTTAGT

Comment: @sara that's probably because you're using a UNIX tool to process a file that uses Windows-style line endings.

Comment: @Tom Fenech So? there is no solution to delete the first 2 char without join all lines together?

Comment: You may be able to use `-b` but calling sed is the wrong approach.

Comment: @Tom Fenech Excuse me! what is -b ?

Comment: Try 's/^../\n/' or on Windows perhaps 's/^../\r\n/' is maybe better. If Cygwin supports the dos2unix utility you could run that over your file. It depends how it's generated really, if you have control over that then changing the line endings of the file when it's generated would stop sed from doing this in the first place.

Comment: I do agree with Tom that using sed is probably the wrong approach but if that's what you're going with then this should work